# Is there any way to fluently receive audio and send it to the backend

Tags: python, flask, getusermedia

I want to create a web application(Flask- A Flashcard AI), a part of which is a bot which needs to directly interact with the human through speech recognition and text-to-speech. I have pyttsx3 and speech_recognition installed for that, where I am confused is how am I supposed to get the user's audio as input and then send it to the backend. I have tried to look up YouTube tutorials and asked other people about the same, the only success I've had is learning about `Navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia`. I want to make the communication fluent, and I will have to send the data to the back-end as well. I am not sure how to send it to the back-end and get the user media fluently, I could use `Navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia` and convert it into an audio file(not sure how to do that yet but I think I'll figure it out eventually, and having the user upload a audio recording won't be nice ***at all***), but then that'll take up a lot of space on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to process some action based on voice you can use speech API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

This API will be able to give you text based captions which you can easily store in the database.

If you need to store audio on server side you would convert that to some loassy format like `mp3` or `aac` to save space.